# Combo with conditional options in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to do a combo options with condtional sub options in google spreadsheet. Here is an example of what I need to do.

[image]

If the option choosen in column A was "Option 1" then options available in column B must be 1, 2, 3 and 4 and If option 2 was choosen in column A then options 5, 6, 7 and 8 must be available in in the B cell of the same row.

Can you help me?

Comment: Relates to this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744547/how-do-you-do-dynamic-dependent-drop-downs-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an example sheet to show one solution:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yquke1pCponpEHjgZWCa7t8RyiWCAr1QR6VnYwJNSVw/edit?usp=sharing

Unfortunately the data validation in each row of Col B has to be adjusted manually so that the row number matches with Sheet2 though.  For this reason it would be a pain to set up for a large number of rows.

I believe secondary validation can also be done by a script though so it may be worth searching one of those out

Comment: Thanks! I will do it in another way! But it can works too!