# Replace INDIRECT() in data validation rule

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a working Excel spreadsheet that used `indirect()` in the data validation and it worked fine. I uploaded it to sheets and converted it, now the indirect does not work.

I have found [a link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/YfQNRsCdoGw/uR3U0NDNAAAJ) on the support forum that explains it does not work in Chrome but appears to work in Firefox, and the answers and workarounds seem to be for generating a secondary list... which is what I want, but in a data validation across a row.

I have knocked up a simple test sheet, hopefully public and the script editor is visible:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KUgrdXKIKlk1DWvDOX9cY3B2VnRH_5h_vKuZJlqUlN8/edit?usp=sharing

Hopefully you can see what I'm after. I want the validation in `C8` to be the list of items in the category based in `B8`; `C9` based on `B9` etc.

**EDIT and Update**

The question is about a replacement to indirect() in a data validation rule. While I did find a way round this by using indirect(), I preferred the version mentioned by Desire (to whom I have attributed the answer), but I thought I'd document my solution in case the sheet above becomes unavailable, or you cannot access it, or you just wanted a bit more detail.

So, for My Demo I have this:

[image: setup of sheet]

In `A1:C5` are my lists of data with the titles.

In the range `B8:B12` I applied a data validation rule of value in range of `A1:C1` - this gives the first dropdown.

In Cell `E8` I put the formula `=transpose(filter($A$2:$C$5, $A$1:$C$1 = B8))` and then copied this down to `E12`

Finally I put the following in a function and ran it in the script editor.

```
function runMeOnce() {
    var dst = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('C8:C12');
    var rules = [];
    for (var i = 8; i < 13; i++) {
      var src = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("E" + i + ":H" + i);
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(src).build();
      rules.push(rule);
    }
    dst.setDataValidations(rules);
}
```

That's all there is, no more `onEdit()` triggering.

**NOTE** There is one downside I bumped into with this method though. I have this in place for 6000+ rows in my actual spreadsheet, and across multiple sheets, with some dropdowns having 50-100 items in. This solution seriously eats into the (current) 2 million cell limit.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Validation rule of the type "List of items" takes only a comma-separated list of values as its parameter, and does not evaluate any formulas you try to put there. It does not matter what the function returns, because it will not be called. If you put, say "=sqrt(A10)" in the field "List of items", that only means that the validation rule will require the string "=sqrt(A10)" to be entered in the cell.

Similarly with "List from a Range". Either what you enter parses as range notation, or it does not. The string "=getValidationRange(B8)" does not parse as range notation, hence the error. The function is never called.

The only type of validation that calls a function is "Custom formula". If you use it, then the validation can be performed as intended: for example,

```
=match(C8, filter(A2:C5, A1:C1 = B8), 0)
```

requires the content of C8 to be in the column of the table A2:C5 under the heading that matches the category in B8. However, with a custom formula you do not get a dropdown in a cell.

To get a dynamic dropdown, one can either

#### Use an auxiliary range

For example, enter `filter(A2:C5, A1:C1 = B8)` in cell F1, so that the F column is for the categories currently selected. The data validation would be "List from a Range", F1:F. This is a fine workaround for one validation rule, but takes more work when you have multiple ones.

#### Use a triggered script

Use a script that is triggered on edit and sets data validation rules  accordingly; this is discussed in [How do you do dynamic / dependent drop downs in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744547/how-do-you-do-dynamic-dependent-drop-downs-in-google-sheets) among other places.

Comment: Using `=transpose(filter($A$2:$C$5, $A$1:$C$1 = B8))` is a better way than mine if you don't have the named ranges already, or are not trying to replace `Indirect()` like I was. The downside to using a trigger is the speed with which it works - i.e. eventually. If you do the transpose filter with the $ranges in E8 thru E12 in my example, then apply the data validation to each cell in C8 thru C12 only once (preferably programmatically) then this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sacrificing a goat issue, I did find a simple(ish) way around the problem that still uses `indirect()`.

Set up the named ranges as previously using the titles in CamelCase. In my example I have CatA, CatB, and CatC - i.e. the white space needs removing.

At the end of a row (or in another sheet) transpose the chosen named range (in cell `E8`: `=transpose(indirect(substitute(B8, " ", "")))` copy this down as far as you need.

At this point it's good to note that because we are unsing builtin functions, the speed is so much better, as can be seen by my example.

Now the painful bit. For each subcategory cell (`C8`, `C9` etc in my example), you need to add the validation independently as a range of `E8:ZZ8` (obviously ZZ8 needs reigning in a bit) and `E9:ZZ9` etc. It doesn't seem to do referential so if you select all the cell in the column, they all only look at the data you specifically type in the box... I might just not have worked out R1C1 notation here, however. I tried.

This can be scripted on GAS to create the R1C1 validation function and then apply it to the range.