# Google Sheets - Auto-select an option from existing dropdown menu based on another cell's data

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-sheets, formula

I have a sheet with a dropdown menu in A1, and a cell A2, with values that will be the result originated from a script.

I want a certain option from the dropdown menu (the first one, to be precise) to be selected automatically when a certain value is present in A2.

Here's a simulation:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x-pmDmB6mbyjXFY0rHOkIzkpNagRJXif9dWNj3TJHkU/edit?usp=sharing

In A1, I want to write the formula:
If A2 is equal or less than zero, I want option 1 to be force displayed/ automatically selected in A1.
If A2 is more than zero, then I want the manually selected option to remain as it is.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with dynamic dependent dropdowns. You'll find a post regarding this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744547/how-do-you-do-dynamic-dependent-drop-downs-in-google-sheets) here and a pretty detailed explanation [link](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/) here as well. (I assume that you want to display different dropdown items depending on your value in A2)

Comment: Not really, I don't want to add new dropdown menus based on a selection on a first dropdown.
I want the value from a cell to select automatically which of the items in a dropdown menu are being displayed in the cell with a dropdown.

Comment: I just submitted an answer, trying to highlight the similarities with dynamic dependent dropdowns. I hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if we're talking about the same thing, but I believe this has a lot in common with how dynamic dependent dropdowns are created in Google Sheets.

The only main difference is that you don't rely on a dropdown choice for your condition, but any cell value of your choice.

[image: If the Value in F1 is negative, only option 'A' is shown in the dropdown.]

[image: If the Value in F2 is positive, all the other options are displayed as well.]

So how does this work?

The value in G1 is:

```
=IF(F1>0,filter(B:B,A:A="POS"),filter(B:B,A:A="NEG"))
```

This basically means that if F1 is greater than zero, only the values in Column B, whose corresponding value in Column A is POS, show up in Column F.

If F1 is zero or less than zero, only the values of Column B, whose corresponding value in Column A is NEG, show up in Column F.

Accordingly, we can now use Column F (the range G1:G8) as a 'dynamic' reference for the data validation of a dropdown. In the example, this was done in F2.

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYcZU1UzTmE) explains the underlying filter mechanism pretty well. I just expanded it with an IF-statement.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the clarification. It's helped a lot! Thanks!